# How do i get a acf repeater field to be 100% width in admin

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I am using ACF Pro Reapter field but for some reason when I apply the form-control boot strap tag its not forcing the repeating field to be 100% width and it is making it look squased.

[image]

And when I go to view it in the benefits post type it is showing as such

[image]

What I want is to have the repeater

Comment: The size in percents is for the table column width. Maybe you have to choose the Row Layout to get what you want

Comment: @Pierre Hi pierre I am quite new to ACF where would i find row layout please

Comment: @Pierre never mind i found it thank you

Comment: @Pierre would you like to create an answer so i can give you the kudos you deserve?.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The size in percents is for the table column width, when you are on the Table Layout.

For a full-width row, you have to choose the Row Layout on your ACF field settings.

Comment: 100% dead on target suprised i didnt see this myself well done

Answer (score -1):

Use "Block" instead of "Table" in the ACF layout for your repeater and configure the block width.

Comment: Do not create a question to comment please look at this
https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead